# Include files in electron-builder?

Tags: python, electron, electron-builder

I'm building an app with ElectronJS that has python working in it, for which I have two additional files, the one that links html to python and the python file itself.

1. linker.js
2. python.py

Basically, if I compile my app and run it, it says that it cannot find those two files, electron-builder compiles excluding those two files. How can I include them?

I tried:

```
"extraResources": [
      "python.py",
      "linker.js"
    ],
- - - - - - - - -
 "files": [
      "python.py",
      "linker.js",
      "**/*"
    ]
- - - - - - - - -
"asar": true,
    "asarUnpack": [
      "linker.js",
      "python.py"
    ]
```

None of these did the trick. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue yet ?